# SQL insert statement in teradata assistant

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

can anybody help me with this please?
I want to insert data in table in Teradata SQL Assistant, but insert only that doesn't exist in the table. 
I have an ideal how to do it in Microsoft SQL Server but not in teradata as i'm new to it.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit] your question accordingly. At the moment it's very broad and there can be many reasons for an insert to apparently not work.

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on your situation.  Can you elaborate a little more by answering the following questions?  I can then give you my best idea of what to do.

1. Are you inserting into an existing table using a select statement from other Teradata tables, or from a file?
2. Does the table you are inserting into have a UPI (unique primary index)?  You can check this by running the following code:

show table database.table;

where "table" is the name of your table and "database" is the database where your table is stored.

The end of the resultset should say either "unique primary index" or simply "primary index."

No matter what the answers are, you will most likely need to use an insert statement, insert-select statement, or a merge statement in the end.  Teradata SQL Assistant has an example of all of these in the Query Builder.  You can bring it up by pressing F2.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, You want to insert some data to a table. A the issue is you only need to insert those rows in the table for-example table A, which does not exist is this table A. The solution depends on your source.

1. If source is another Teradata table that is table B, then you could use a join between Table A and Table B so detect which are not already there.
2. If source is some other database or a file, than I would suggest to insert data to a temporary table and then use the same logic as given in point-1.

Br,
Hassam